# Can I have multiple $_GET with the different key, same values?

Tags: php, google-custom-search

I have search over the internet but did not get actual solution. What I found is  "**multiple $_GET with the same key, different values?**" but I want to know that how can set different key with same value like **?t=helloWorld&?q=helloWorld**, I know it is possible but I don't know the procedure to make this happen. Anyone can   help me.?

So, My Question is 
I want to use [www.omdbapi.com](http://www.omdbapi.com) API and Google CSE together where omdb needs key '?t=' and [Google CSE](https://cse.google.co.in) need '?q=' I have implemented both on [www.moviesnight.club](http://www.moviesnight.club) but it is not working because I can't duplicate the value of key '?t=' for the key '?q='.

Comment: Yes, you can set many GET parameters with the same value. What is the question?

Comment: `header("Location: index.php?t=helloWord&q=helloWord");` or even a form with a `GET` method.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I want to use www.omdbapi.com API and Google CSE together where omdb needs key '?t=' and Google CSE need '?q='    I have implemented both on www.moviesnight.club but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found any solution using only PHP so the JavaScript help me to make it done. Check the following snippets.

**JavaScript**

```
function changeText(containerId) {
    var datatext = document.getElementById('omdbBox').value;
    var collection = document.getElementById(containerId).getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var x = 0; x < collection.length; x++) {
        if (collection[x].type.toUpperCase() == 'TEXT') collection[x].value = datatext;
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
#cseBox {display: none;}
```

**PHP** (to print the submitted URL, you don't have to use this php code while using it, it is just for test purpose. It will make sure that code is working.)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    echo 'http://moviesnight.club/?<b>t='.$_GET['t'].'&q='.$_GET['q'].'</b>&search=';
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="get">
    <input id="omdbBox" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="t" onkeyup="changeText('cseBox')">
    <div id="cseBox">
        <input type="text" name="q">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="search">
</form>
```

Also check the live **[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2f04-6k5u)**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You should store the value of the parameter in a variable an check which key is available in `$_GET`:

```
$queryValue = '';

// Fetch parameter for omdbapi
if(isset($_GET['t'])) {
    $queryValue = $_GET['t'];
}

// Fetch parameter for Google CSE
if(isset($_GET['g'])) {
    $queryValue = $_GET['g'];
}

// Optional:
if(empty($queryValue)) {
    die('No parameter given.');
}

// Use the value stored in $queryValue
```

**Solution 2: (If you don't have the possibility to use a variable like `$queryValue`)**

```
$_GET['g'] = isset($_GET['g']) ? : $_GET['t'];
$_GET['t'] = isset($_GET['t']) ? : $_GET['g'];
```

Comment: I have use the solution 2 but it is still empty http://moviesnight.club/?t=Spectre&q=&search=